# Llamar a método Vuejs desde Jquery

Tags: jquery, vue.js, datatables

Estoy implementando una tabla de DataTables en un componente Vue y hasta ahora funciona a la perfección la carga. El problema es que deseo agregar botones para editar y no tengo mucha idea de Jquery, pero gracias al siguiente código logro obtener el ID de la fila seleccionada. El tema es que necesito pasar ese valor a un método llamado verCliente(id_cliente) y no se como realizarlo. Tienen idea de como poder hacerlo?

```
$('#clientes tbody').on('click', '.verCliente', function () {
                       
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var id_cliente = table.row( row ).data().id;
        //console.log(id_cliente);
        //probé con this.verCliente(id_cliente) pero el error me dice que no es función
                        
});

verCliente(id_cliente){
  let me=this;
  me.modal=2;
  me.tituloModal = 'Historial de cliente';
  
  $('.compras').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
  var url= '/cliente/verCliente?id=' + id_cliente;
  axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
  var respuesta= response.data;
  me.arrayDatos = respuesta.datos;      
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
 },
```

Comment: Hola ¿Dónde y cómo está definida la función _verCliente_?

Comment: Algo como esto:  var id_cliente=document.getElementById("TuID").value
Donde "TuID" es el nombre de tu ID a traer.

Comment: si esto es vue, entonces no deberias usar jquery para absolutamente nada, nunca, de los nunca. Es vue, tiene un dom virtual, y se usa justamente para no tener que usar jquery para absolutamente nada.... ahora que entendiste eso... tenes un problema?

Comment: Gracias a todos por su tiempo, no usare jquery gracias

Answer (score 1):

La integración de JQuery con VueJS es posible, pero si ya estás trabajando con vue te recomiendo hacer todo ahí. En ocasiones utilizamos librerías de JQuery porque simplemente no existen en VueJs o no hay un equivalente, por lo cual es importante saber como hacer que estos dos ambientes convivan.

La clave está en asignar la instancia de vue a una variable para luego utilizarla donde desees.

```js
// Instancia de JQuery
$(()=>{
  $('#call-vue-function').click(()=>{
    vue.hola()
  })
  
  $('#call-vue-property').click(()=>{
    alert(vue.some_prop)
  })
})


// Instancia de vuejs

let vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      'some_prop' : 'Hola, soy una propiedad de vue'
    }
  },
  methods : {
    hola(){
       alert('Hola, soy el metodo de vue')
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<button id="call-vue-function">Call vue function</button>
<button id="call-vue-property">Call vue property</button>
<div id="app"></div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```